# Django access pk id in class

Tags: python, django

I have this site, and I want to be able to have views. When you go to url /post/int:pk it shows the post in more detail. When the user goes here, I want to add one to an field in models.py. Here is models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    people_read = models.IntegerField(default=0) # Add one to this data
    user_liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_liked')
    user_disliked = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_disliked')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

And views.py:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.people_read = post.people_read + 1
    post.save()
```

The problem with this is that it won't get the pk id. So how do I get the posts pk in an class, or is there another way to add to a models field when going to a url? Thanks.

Comment: As noted in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), the `DetailView` class already has the object in question when it is executing (While this view is executing, `self.object` will contain the object that the view is operating upon.). You would just have to override the `get` method to increment the `people_read` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.blog_view += 1
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

This works for me, I get_object of self and it works and I am able to use it.